# Potential position and value of an element in array

Tags: php, arrays, range

Array have a range of keys with it's proper values.

Let's say that array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.00
    [2] => 0.60
    [5] => 1.00
    [1] => 0.30
    [3] => 0.90
)
```

So, it's without key 4.

Since array is in fact a range of elements, value of element with key 4 will be 0.90, or value of element with first lower key value.

What will be best practice to achieve, to get value 0.90 for value of 4 (that does not exist in array).

Hope that my question in not to complicated... Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why would the value of element 4 be 0.9? You already have an element with a value of 0.9 (element 3). What is the logic behind those values? Is the value of the missing element always going to be the same as the value of the previous existent element?

Comment: as I understand there are 2 different rules here: `[4] => 0.9` because the value `0.9` is at the position `[4]` (although the key is actually `[3]`). The other rule as you said (*or value of element with first lower key value*) should be the value at the key `[0]` (the first key having the lower value than `[4]`), then it should be `[4] => 0`. So what do actually you want here? (I'm even not sure if my understanding is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't call this a **best practice**, but it would give you the value you expect, that is: **the value in the first entry in the array with key lower than the given one**.

```
function findValue( $i, $values ) 
{
    if ( $i < 0 ) die ("Can't compute.");

    if ( !isset( $values[$i] ) )
    { 
        return findValue( $i-1, $values );
    }
    else
    {
        return $values[$i];
    }
}


$values = array(
 0 => 0.0,
 2 => 0.6,
 5 => 1.0,
 1 => 0.3,
 3 => 0.9
);

$searchedValue = findValue(4, $values);
```